# Multiple checkboxes with vee-validate and oruga ui in a nuxt 3 project

Tags: forms, validation, nuxtjs3, vee-validate, nuxt3

How to validate a multiple checkboxes field, with [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/) using [oruga ui](https://oruga.io) in a [Nuxt 3](https://nuxt.com/) project.

I have a Nuxt 3 project with Oruga ui and vee-validate.

I successfully developed a form thanks to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/3575#issuecomment-1518429139).

But I'm stuck with a field where I want to validate a multiple checkbox.

I have basically tried to adapt a working multiselect field, without success.

I have 2 reproductions with two different coding attempts, that I link below, where you can also see the working multiselect field.

In the [first](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-5bhtnh?file=pages%2Findex.vue) one I used this code that is basically the same as the working multiselect, with a few changes:

```js
    <VField
      name="multicheckbox"
      label="Multicheckbox"
      v-slot="{ handleChange, handleBlur, checkedValue, errors }"
      v-model="form.multicheckbox"
    >
      <OField
        label="Multicheckbox"
        :variant="errors[0] ? 'danger' : null"
        :message="errors[0] ? errors[0] : ''"
      >
        <OCheckbox
          v-for="option in options"
          :key="option"
          :model-value="checkedValue"
          @input="handleChange"
          @update:modelValue="handleChange"
          @change="handleChange"
          @blur="handleBlur"
          :native-value="option"
        >{{ option }}</OCheckbox>
      </OField>
    </VField>
```

In the [second](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-f5qzep?file=pages%2Findex.vue) one I tried to use `checkedValue` and `uncheckedValue` properties as documented [here](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/examples/custom-checkboxes/), as follow:

```js
    <VField
      name="multicheckbox"
      label="Multicheckbox"
      v-slot="{ handleChange, handleBlur, checkedValue, errors, checked }"
      v-model="form.multicheckbox"
    >
      <OField
        label="Multicheckbox"
        name="options"
        :variant="errors[0] ? 'danger' : null"
        :message="errors[0] ? errors[0] : ''"
      >
        <OCheckbox
          v-for="option in options"
          :key="option"
          type="checkbox"
          name="options"
          checkedValue: true,
          uncheckedValue: false,
          :model-value="checked"
          @input="handleChange"
          @update:modelValue="handleChange"
          @change="handleChange"
          @blur="handleBlur"
          :native-value="option"
        >{{ option }}</OCheckbox>
      </OField>
    </VField>
```

In both cases, when I select two boxes, only the last selected is stored instead of an array as documented [here](https://oruga.io/components/checkbox.html) in the Array section.

How can I use the two libraries together to validate a multiple checkbox field?